# How to pass Object to NgStyle directive in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I'm trying to use `NgStyle` directive with an object variable like so:

```
@Component({
      template: `
            <div [ngStyle]="object">
              some test text
           </div>`
    })

export class example {
    private object: string = "{background-color: 'white'}";
}
```

I also tried with `object = "background-color: 'red'"` and `[ngStyle]="{object}"`, but it seems like it doesn't work. I get the message error:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error caused by: Cannot find a differ supporting object '{color: 'white'}'(…)consoleError @ VM1051 zone.js@0.6.21?main=browser:346_loop_1 @ VM1051 zone.js@0.6.21?main=browser:371drainMicroTaskQueue @ VM1051 zone.js@0.6.21?main=browser:375ZoneTask.invoke @ VM1051 zone.js@0.6.21?main=browser:297

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "As an object, like so" but you pass a string.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Don't pass a `string` to [`[ngStyle]`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle), pass an `Object` and it will work:

```
private object: Object = { 'background-color': 'red'};
```

Comment: template-bindable properties should be public

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar issue with ngStyle, and fixed it as follows:

```
[ngStyle]="{'top.px':dtPickerTop, 'left.px':dtPickerLeft}"
```

dtPickerTop & dtPickerLeft are set in my component based on a click event.

Adding the `.px` made it work, whereas without it, it didn't seem to.

Answer (score 0):

## You can also use CSS-in-JS object syntax

this way, instead of surrounding property strings with quotes, you can just pass'em camelCased, just like a regular JS object

```
<div [ngStyle]="{backgroundColor: 'red', borderRadius: '10px', width: '100px' }">

</div>
```

And to have a cleaner template, you can always define your styles object in the TS file...

=> .ts

```
export class MyComponent  {
 
   // ...
  
   stylesObj = {backgroundColor: 'red', borderRadius: '10px', width: '100px' }
}
```

=> .html

```
<div [ngStyle]="stylesObj">

</div>
```